# what does this shellscript do?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# clear_ram.sh - Clear as much user-space ram as possible 
#                       (until the OOM_killer gets us)
#

       swapoff -a
       mem=$(free -b | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}')
       mount none -t tmpfs -o size=$mem /tmp
       dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero.dat bs=1M &
       echo "17" > /proc/$(pidof dd)/oomadj
       while (pidof dd); do kill -USR1 $(pidof dd); done
```

this is a shell script.
what does this code do?

NOT HOMEWORK

Comment: It tells you in the notes... It clears space in ram.

Comment: It's a script for automatically lowering your rep on Stack Overflow.

Comment: duuh, Gaz
i want details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script

- deactivates swap
- obtains the amount of RAM in bytes
- mounts a ramdisk equal to available RAM
- writes zeros to the ramdisk via dd
- Attempts to set the `dd` process to be first on the chopping block for the Out Of Memory killer
- prints the process ID of `dd` and its current status for as long as it keeps running

I say "attempts" because it should be writing to `oom_adj` and not `oomadj`, at least for recent kernels, and because the max value is 15 and not 17.

There's also a bug here, because it will print the PID and status for **all** executing `dd`, not just the one in the script.

As the comment says, eventually the kernel Out Of Memory killer will kill the process.

I'm pretty sure it's a silly thing to do. I don't know of a reason why you would actually need to zero memory this way.

Comment: sending usr1 to dd causes it to print out a progress report of what it's doing.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks. I had read this somewhere before, but had to go back to the man page to be sure. I have edited my answer.